# UTF8 Encoding problem - in Java and VC interaction

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I have a Java application, which makes an socket connection with a VC applications and send a String over that. This string is UTF8 encoded before sending.

Die to security requirements, I need to encrypt certain part of the String; in this encryption some character are generated for whom ASCII value is greater than 128.

When I send such characters over socket connection and convert those back to ANSI, those are changed to ? in the receiving VC application.

I am not able to find out what maybe causing it; please help.

Regards

Nitin

Comment: Encryption typically takes arbitrary bytes and returns arbitrary bytes. If the input is text, it would have a character encoding. If the output needs to be transmitted as text, one might use Base64. Why do you mention 3 character encodings or families: UTF-8, ASCII, ANSI? Can't you just use UTF-8?

Comment: Hi, we are using only ANSI and UTF-8. VC application is a legacy one and accepts input in UTF-8; changes it to ANSI and pass it on to another application. We can't change it.